# ValueError: unsupported format character 'a' (0x61) at index 55 with URL string

Tags: python, string, url, pymysql

Attempting to send a URL and hostName into a database with the following code:

```
def sendToDatabase(self, case, filename):
103         ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
104         filenoext = filename.strip(ext)
105         url = "https://apses4859.ms.ds.uhc.com:10943/rest/download/C%3A/IBM/ISA5/ISA5/isa/cases/%s/%s-analyzer_ISA_PD/%s_Leak_Suspects/index.html" % (case, filename,filenoext)
106         cursor = connection.cursor()
107         m = re.search(r"([^.]*)", filename)
108         hostname = m.group(1)
109         query = "INSERT INTO StoryData (hostName, reportName) VALUES (%s, %s)"
110         cursor.execute(query , (hostname, url))
111         connection.commit()
112         cursor.close()
```

It's not liking the A next to %3A for some reason. I've tried adding an extra % in and it still doesn't affect it. Not quite understanding why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I tried it, too, and it worked OK for me. (`%%3A` instead of `%3A`)

Answer (score 1):

`%3A` is being interpreted as a formatting string, and there's no `A` format. Better switch to new-style formatting, ie. using `format` method instead of `%` operator:

```
url = "https://apses4859.ms.ds.uhc.com:10943/rest/download/C%3A/IBM/ISA5/ISA5/isa/cases/{}/{}-analyzer_ISA_PD/{}_Leak_Suspects/index.html".format(case, filename,filenoext)
```